# How to make html5 canvas shape resizable

Tags: html, function, resize, kineticjs, mousedown

check out: http://jsfiddle.net/aqaP7/4/,

and

http://shedlimited.debrucellc.com/test3/canvaskinclip.html,

I want to make html5 images resizable,
and it needs to be based on the html5 etc because my clipping region is in html5

I think that it will have to do with the mousedown events, but how for example can I tell if the
mouse is on the corner of the shape? Can I just add the code to my circle - mousedown function?

```
 circle.on("mousedown", function(){
            draggingShape = this;
            var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
            draggingRectOffsetX = mousePos.x - circle._x;
            draggingRectOffsetY = mousePos.y - circle._y;
        });
        circle.on("mouseover", function(){
            document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
        });
        circle.on("mouseout", function(){
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";
        });

        layer.add(circle);

        stage.on("mouseout", function(){
            draggingShape = undefined;
        }, false);

        stage.on("mousemove", function(){
            var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
            if (draggingShape) {
                draggingShape._x = mousePos.x - draggingRectOffsetX;
                draggingShape._y = mousePos.y - draggingRectOffsetY;

                layer.draw();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this canvas tutorial:

[Take a look at this tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-modify-curves-with-anchor-points-using-kineticjs/)

Here is some simple code to get you started:

```
var anchor;

function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
  var stage = group.getStage();
  var layer = group.getLayer();

  anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    stroke: "#666",
    fill: "#ddd",
    strokeWidth: 2,
    radius: 8,
    name: name,
    draggable: true
  });

  anchor.on("dragmove", function() {
    update(group, this);
    layer.draw();
  });
  anchor.on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
    group.setDraggable(false);
    this.moveToTop();
  });
  anchor.on("dragend", function() {
    group.setDraggable(true);
    layer.draw();
  });
  // add hover styling
  anchor.on("mouseover", function() {
    var layer = this.getLayer();
    document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
    this.setStrokeWidth(4);
    layer.draw();
  });
  anchor.on("mouseout", function() {
    var layer = this.getLayer();
    document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    this.setStrokeWidth(2);
    layer.draw();
  });

  group.add(anchor);
}
```

Essentially, you want to add anchors to a shape on click, then use those anchors for resizing.